# VBA passing word.table to subroutine using object variable

Tags: vba, object, ms-word

I've stuck with something I cannot understand (but I' aware that it might be quite simple). I try some general-use routine to collect attributes of typical word objects such as tables, textboxes, ranges etc. Here goes the idea:

```
Sub GetWobjectAttributes(ByRef WObject As Object)

    If TypeOf WObject Is Word.Table Then
            'grab table attributes
        ElseIf TypeOf WObject Is Word.Range Then
            'grab range attributes
        ...

        End If
    End Sub
```

Unfortunately, passing object using generic object type seems to change the type of passed object. For example executing sub test:

```
Sub test()


GetWobjectAttributes (ThisDocument.Tables(1))

'MsgBox (TypeName(ThisDocument.Range.Tables(1)))

End Sub


Public Sub GetWobjectAttributes(ByRef WObject As Variant)

    MsgBox (TypeName(WObject))

End Sub
```

displaying message:

> Range instead of "Table" (but executing MsgBox (TypeName(ThisDocument.Range.Tables(1))) directly in test sub (commented in example) displaying: Table.

Any ideas how to pass object of unkown type to subroutine without type changing?

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you call the Sub as a Function (by adding () around the parameter). This apparently returns the 'default member' i.e. Range.

Call the sub like a Sub by removing the () around the parameter and it will both return Table:

```
Sub test()

   GetWobjectAttributes ThisDocument.Tables(1)

   MsgBox (TypeName(ThisDocument.Range.Tables(1)))

End Sub


Public Sub GetWobjectAttributes(ByRef WObject As Variant)

   MsgBox (TypeName(WObject))

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, now it's obvious.  I had some brain fade:/ Solution works perfectly.